# PHP 5.4 replaces [ in parameters with specialchars

Tags: php

I am working on an xtCommerce Shop which seems to have problems with PHP 5.4 (at least it was running fine before on lower versions).
Current problem is, that PHP seems to replace brackets for ids with `specialchars` Example:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1234" name="ids[]"></input>
</form>
```

when send `print_r($_GET)` shows:
`[ids%5B%5D] => 1234`

I've not seen this before, anyone a helping hand please?

Another example:
from multiple

```
<select name="group_name[5933]">
    <option value="1"></option>
</select>
```

`print_r($_GET)` shows:

```
[group_name%5B5933%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B5934%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B5940%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B61432%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B61576%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B61598%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B62579%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B90287%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B90288%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B103035%5D] => 1
[group_name%5B109678%5D] => 1
```

Third example, different page, with post:

```
    <form method="post" action="http://xxxx/admin/cross_sell_groups.php?page=1&action=insert" name="status">
<input type="text" name="cross_sell_group_name[2]"></input>
</form>
```

and here is the $_POST just empty, only $_GET is set.

Comment: PHP is not replacing that, it's the browser when sending the data (unless you can clarify what happens exactly). That's a legitimate thing to do.

Comment: I will disagree here, if you send it, print_r will show an array with a values in. Additionally else it should work and not return with no input

Comment: I'd suspect JS in the page before PHP. What does the raw HTTP request look like according to the Net tab of your browser developer tools?

Comment: the raw http looks like `http://XXXX/admin/categories.php?action=edit_crossselling&special=add_entries&current_product_id=60828&cpath=647_251&ids%5B%5D=5933&group_name%5B5933%5D=1&group_name%5B5934%5D=1&group_name%5B5940%5D=1&group_name%5B61432%5D=1&group_name%5B61576%5D=1&group_name%5B61598%5D=1&group_name%5B62579%5D=1&group_name%5B90287%5D=1&group_name%5B90288%5D=1&group_name%5B103035%5D=1&group_name%5B109678%5D=1` the browser developer tools shows brackets on mouse hover though even they are not shown here when I copy it (Firefox 28), and no js involved, shop worked ago on a server w PHP5.2

Comment: it may be worth looking at the php.ini to ensure that things like 'magic_quotes' were 'off' when using php 5.2. Or to just see what the differences are now. i do appreciate that is a 'desperate' suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like some JavaScript is to blame here. If your form is being submitted via AJAX, look into that.

If I'm wrong and this is not an AJAX form, it's possible there's a PHP configuration error or you have an old version of PHP, but I'd say AJAX is more likely to be at fault.

Comment: javascript isn't involved, wasn't added or changed, the shop worked a week ago with PHP 5.2, now running under 5.4 and it shows that error. The error doesn't appear on just form but many using arrays as parameter. And hey, xtCommerce and AJAX, you must be joking :)